# Using pgLogical row filter for jsonB column type

Tags: postgresql, replication, pglogical

I am trying to replicate a table that contains jsonB column. I want to use row filtering to select only the rows that I need. How do I define the row filter for jsonB?

Table person:

```
        id                  serial,
        name                TEXT NOT NULL,
        details          JSONB NOT NULL,
        modified_at         TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
        PRIMARY KEY (name));
```

Sample data:

```
 id |  name   |     details     |          modified_at          
----+---------+-----------------+-------------------------------
  1 | person1 | {"city": "nyc"} | 2021-05-17 06:05:55.735086+00
  2 | person2 | {"city": "SF"}  | 2021-05-17 06:06:30.028065+00
```

I have tried the following and they don't work:

```
SELECT pglogical.replication_set_add_table(set_name:= 'replicate1', relation := 'person', row_filter:= details->>'city' = 'nyc');
```

The other option I tried:

```
SELECT pglogical.replication_set_add_table(set_name:= 'replicate1', relation := 'person', row_filter:= "details->>'city' = 'nyc'");
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: `:=` for providing values for named parameters is deprecated in favor of the standard compliant `=>` operator.

Comment: I would assume `row_filter` is a varchar/text parameter, so it should probably be: `row_filter => 'details->>''city'' = ''nyc'''`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you, didn't realize it was deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution can be found here: https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/pglogical/issues/332